# How to add integrity check (e.g. HMAC) to the ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, csrf, data-integrity, antiforgerytoken

I have been developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application that uses the MVC AntiForgeryToken to prevent CSRF attacks. Lately the application was audited by an security company and they claimed to have found a vulnerability in the AntiForgeryToken that we are using. The problem is that the token does not have an integrity check. It is possible to alter the token slightly and it will still pass as an valid token.

Is it possible to extend the basic ASP.NET MVC AntiForgeryToken so that it will include an integrity check (e.g. HMAC)? Are there any existing implementations available? Or do I simply need to write my own implementation of the CSRF token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

In don't understand why there would be a vulnerability since the token is encrypted using System.Web.Security.MachineKey. You can customize which algorithms to use (HMAC is the default algo for validation) in [machineKey element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Original:

The easiest way I can think of is to append your own secure token to the AntiForgeryToken by providing an IAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider.

```
public class UserAgentAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider : IAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider
{
    public string GetAdditionalData(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        return GenerateToken(context);
    }

    public bool ValidateAdditionalData(HttpContextBase context, string additionalData)
    {
        return string.Equals(GenerateToken(context), additionalData, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    private string GenerateToken(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        return context.Request.UserAgent; //DON'T DO THIS IN PRODUCTION
    }
}
```

In Global.asax.cs

```
AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider = new UserAgentAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is certainly a step to the right direction but I'm not sure how I go about creating an integrity check for the AntiForgeryToken. Shouldn't I be able to access the actual token that is created in order to derive integrity check data from it? Adding additional data can make the AntiForgeryToken more secure but it does not seem to provide a way to do the integrity check?

Comment: You can do the integrity check in your additional data (only). If the additional data is invalid, MVC treats the anti forgery token as invalid. I don't see a way to customize the whole token unless you implement your own Html.Helper.AntiForgeryToken() and ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining what the options are and clarifying the issue. I don't either understand why there would be an vulnerability and all my attempts to corrupt the AntiForgeryToken have resulted in an exception being thrown. Even though I don't have an implementation of the AntiForgeryToken that includes an integrity check I now have something very concrete to reply to the security company that audited our application.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at the concept of stateless CSRF protection. There are 2 standard approaches to achieving this: the Encrypted Token Pattern and the Double Submit Cookie pattern. The [Encrypted Token Pattern](http://insidethecpu.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/encrypted-token-pattern/) leverages a Rijndael-encrypted Token whose integrity is maintained by a SHA256 hashing algorithm.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll look into that when I have time to start implementing a custom token. Right now the built in one will do.